# Yelp restaurants info web scraping (encountering error when running a loop to get multiple restaurants information)

Tags: r, web-scraping

Trying to web scrape restaurant information from Yelp such as the price range ($$$$), price description, alcohol, phone, website, health score. The code works perfectly fine for 2 restaurants - Dirty French and Uncle Boons but it starts to show an error when using the same code for the restaurant Legacy Records. This is because of the XPath that I have used in the code for alcohol (and website which is not shown in the code) is different for Dirty French and Uncle Boons and for Legacy Records. Also, there is no price range for Legacy Records but it is still showing up in the output.

Is there any way that I can loop through different restaurants and get the required information even when the XPath is kept constant, or, anyway such that the XPath changes by itself for every restaurant? I am collecting data for more than 1000 restaurants so can't think of changing the code manually every time.

Am I even going in the right direction? Is there a better way?

This code can very well be reproduced in your system.

```
actual_name <- data.frame(actual_name = c("dirty-french-new-york", "uncle- 
boons-new-york", 
                                      "legacy-records-new-york"))


titles <- c()
urls <- c()

urls <- paste(initial, actual_name$actual_name, sep = "")

map_df(urls, function(i){
  url <- read_html(i)

  data.frame(Title = url %>% html_node("title") %>% html_text(),
         HealthScore = url %>% html_node(".health-score-description") %>% 
html_text(), 
         Rating = url %>%
           html_node(xpath = "//*   [@id='wrap']/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div") 
%>%
           html_attr("title"),
         Phone = url %>% html_node(".biz-phone") %>% html_text(),
         Price = url %>% html_node(".price-range") %>% html_text(),
         PriceDescription = url %>% html_node(".price-description") %>% 
html_text(),
         Alcohol = url %>%
           html_nodes(xpath = "//* [@id='wrap']/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[3]/span[2]/a") %>%
           html_text())
}) -> titles
```